# Undefined offset: 0 with PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, offset

I have the following code in my Symfony 2 web project in one of my repositories:

```
 $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
 $converted = $this->transformArray($result);
 return $converted[0];
```

**My problem:**

I get the following error which points to the last line:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

**Background:**

My function `transformArray()` does the following:

```
 private function transformArray($rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $i => $row) {
            $rows[$i]['hexcolor'] = $this->convertColor($row['colorR'], $row['colorG'], $row['colorB']);
        };

        return $rows;
    }
```

After this operation, my variable `$converted` contains an array like this with only one result:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'subjectId' => 1234,
    'subjectName' => 'English',
    'hexcolor' => '#ff00'
  )
)
```

Can anyone explain why doing `$converted[0]` (= trying to access the 0 index) results in an undefined offset error? Pasting the array output into a PHPFiddle and trying to access the 0 index works totally fine. How come it does not in my Symfony 2 project?

Comment: Post your transformArray() value

Comment: Confirm that `$result` has a value (ie, your query isn't failing)?

Comment: I would: To see the first entry in any array: `reset $converted;` then: `current($converted);` will get the value of the first entry and `key($converted);`  with get the index of that entry. This works for all PHP arrays.

Comment: 'key($converted)' gives me 0. But why then there is still this offset error???

Comment: debugging: `var_dump(!empty($converted), $converted);` Should return `true` and either an array or an object that implements `ArrayAccess`. Whatever, you  will see what is causing the undefined index when you try an access it.

Answer (score 0):

This is where going a little extra Mile with your code comes in handy. By that, it is meant something so simple as adding a few extra lines of code like so:

```
<?php   
    $result     = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    // DOES THE QUERY EVEN RETURN ANY RESULTS?
    // IF NOT, SET $converted TO EMPTY ARRAY: WHY NOT? 
    $converted  = (!empty($result)) ? $this->transformArray($result) : array();

    // RETURN $converted[0] ONLY IF IT EXISTS, OTHERWISE NULL
    return isset($converted[0]) ? $converted[0] : null;
```